# Why isn't initWithCoder initializing items correctly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uistoryboard, initwithcoder

I've got a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. My subclass contains several `UILabel`s. I want my subclass to initialize these labels to some default settings that applies to every table view cell of mine.

I read that I should be using `initWithCoder` for this. My `initWithCoder` function is being called, and I can step through each line in my function and it appears to go through the motions. When I run my application I do not see any of the properties being applied, though. Most noticeably, the font is not being changed. I just don't think any of the properties that I'm modifying on my `UILabel`s are actually being saved, or displayed.

I'm using this subclass in conjunction with a `Storyboard`. I know my changes will not be reflected on the `Storyboard`, but they're also not being reflected when the application runs - despite my code being executed.

Edit: I wanted to mention that prior to trying to override `initWithCoder`, I had an instance method in these subclasses that I'd run this logic in. I would just call that instance method inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This method was working, but I thought it'd be handy to have this logic in this subclass occur automatically.

Any ideas? My code is below:

```
#import "ThreadListCell.h"

@implementation ThreadListCell

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {

        // adjust the font settings of the title
        self.title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Black" size:16];
        self.title.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.267f alpha:1.0f];

        // adjust the font settings of the subtitle
        self.text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Light" size:14];
        self.text.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.267f alpha:0.9f];
        self.text.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];

        // adjust the font settings of the location
        self.location.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Light" size:8];
        self.location.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.267f alpha:0.9f];

        // adjust the UILabel settings of the title
        self.title.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.title.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;

        // adjust the UILabel settings of the subtitle
        self.text.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.text.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;

        // adjust the UILabel settings of the location
        self.location.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.location.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
        self.location.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

    }

    return self;

}

@end
```

And the header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThreadListCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *text;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *location;

@end
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

None of your IBOutlets is set when you get the message - you need to use "awakeFromNib" or "viewDidLoad" - something like that - to access your outlets. That said, you can set other non-outlet stuff in the initWithCoder.

Comment: Oh, ok. Replacing `initWithCoder` with `awakeFromNib` seems to work as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Although, it looks like `awakeFromNib` occurs before I set any of my properties in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This makes me think that perhaps my instance method was the better approach, because I could reliably perform resizing operations based on the current text in a `UILabel`, etc.

Comment: The order should be: initWithCoder, awakeFromNib, cellForRowAtIndexPath. If you need to "preset" some math values, you can do it in the init routine. But you don't have access to your outlets until the nib is loaded.