# Which init method for UIView will be called when using drag and drop in xib file

Tags: ios, initialization, uicollectionviewcell

here is the custom collection view,and below label is the (rating view i design).
[image]

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        [self initGrayStarView];

        [self initYellowStarView];

        [self initRatingLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

but i find that it every time the rating view didn't appear(image view and label did).  then i found it's because that i didn't call the init method for rating view,so it's nil ,but why?
this is the init method.

> but it never call it ,it only call the layoutSubview method.

Comment: Views made in a storyboard call initWithCoder:

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write init method for custom UIView class with xib file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123898/how-to-write-init-method-for-custom-uiview-class-with-xib-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this sort of pattern...

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self _setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder]) {
        [self _setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)_setup {
    blah;
    blah;
    blah;
}
```

Try to "know what is happening" but that will get you through if you're just getting started.

Comment: Although i have found out how to solve my problem,but this is more than i want,i really helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the awakeFromNib: method. Override it in your implementation file like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];
  // Initialization code
  [self setupStuff];
}
```